# How do I get my view to update after an item was removed from my store/State in React with Redux

Tags: javascript, postgresql, reactjs, redux

I am new to React and Redux and just getting comfortable with the idea of managing state and React in general. I preface that as I may need the possible solution to be in the context of what I have—essentially so I will better understand it. :)

That being said this is my problem:

I have created a list/form component in React but having trouble with two glaring problems.

While the item gets removed for the database, 
it is only reflected in the view upon a refresh
You may have noticed the list # or the ID column doesn't subtract when items are removed from the list.
I am using PostgreSQL on the backend and Sequelize as my Object/Relational Mapper and React for my views/components.

I have provided a gif so you all can see what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

React: Student.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import store from "../store";
import { deleteStudent } from "../reducers";

export default class Students extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = store.getState();
    this.deleteStudent = this.deleteStudent.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      this.setState(store.getState());
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  deleteStudent(index) {
    store.dispatch(deleteStudent(index));
    this.setState(store.getState());
  }

  render() {
    var students = this.props.students;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="sixteen columns">
          <h1 className="remove-bottom">Students</h1>
          <h5>List of current students and their campus</h5>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="sixteen columns">
          <div className="example">
            <div>
              <table className="u-full-width">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Campus</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {students.map(function(student, index) {
                    return (
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td>
                          {student.id}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {student.name}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {student.email}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {student.campus}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a
                            className="button button-icon"
                            onClick={() => {
                              console.log(student.id);
                              this.deleteStudent(student.id);
                            }}
                            key={index}
                          >
                            <i className="fa fa-remove" />
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  }, this)}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*StudentForm.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import store from "../store";
import { postStudent } from "../reducers";

const blankFormState = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  campus: ""
};

export default class StudentForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = blankFormState;
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    store.dispatch(postStudent(this.state));
    this.setState(blankFormState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="twelve columns">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="four columns">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input
                    className="u-full-width"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="four columns">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input
                    className="u-full-width"
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="four columns">
                  <label>Campus</label>
                  <input
                    className="u-full-width"
                    type="text"
                    name="campus"
                    value={this.state.campus}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <input className="button-primary" type="submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My *reducer.js*

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import axios from "axios";

const logError = console.error.bind(console);

// INITIAL STATE

const initialState = {
  students: [],
  campuses: []
};

//ACTION CREATORS

const UPDATE_NAME = "UPDATE_NAME";
const ADD_STUDENT = "ADD_STUDENT";
const DELETE_STUDENT = "DELETE_STUDENT";
const GET_STUDENTS = "GET_STUDENTS";
const UPDATE_CAMPUS = "UPDATE_CAMPUS";
const GET_CAMPUS = "GET_CAMPUS";
const GET_CAMPUSES = "GET_CAMPUSES";

// ACTION CREATORS

export function updateName(name) {
  const action = {
    type: UPDATE_NAME,
    name
  };
  return action;
}

export function addStudent(student) {
  return {
    type: ADD_STUDENT,
    student
  };
}

export function scrubStudent(student) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_STUDENT,
    student
  };
}

export function getStudents(students) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_STUDENTS,
    students
  };
  return action;
}

export function updateCampus(campus) {
  const action = {
    type: UPDATE_CAMPUS,
    campus
  };
  return action;
}

export function getCampus(campus) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_CAMPUS,
    campus
  };
  return action;
}

export function getCampuses(campuses) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_CAMPUSES,
    campuses
  };
  return action;
}

//THUNK CREATORS

export function fetchStudents() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get("/api/students")
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(students => {
        dispatch(getStudents(students));
      })
      .catch(logError);
  };
}

export function postStudent(student) {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .post("/api/students", student)
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(function(newStudent) {
        return dispatch(addStudent(newStudent));
      })
      .catch(logError);
  };
}

export function deleteStudent(id) {
  // console.log("student", student);
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .delete("/api/students" + "/" + id)
      .then(function(id) {
        return dispatch(scrubStudent(id));
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return console.error("Removing student: " + id + " unsuccessful", err);
      });
  };
}

export function fetchCampuses() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get("/api/campuses")
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(function(campuses) {
        return dispatch(getCampuses(campuses));
      })
      .catch(logError);
  };
}

export function postCampus(student) {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .post("/api/campuses", campus)
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(function(newCampus) {
        return dispatch(getCampus(newCampus));
      })
      .catch(logError);
  };
}

// REDUCER

const rootReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
  var newState = Object.assign({}, state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_STUDENTS:
      newState.students = state.students.concat(action.students);
      return newState;

    case ADD_STUDENT:
      newState.students = state.students.concat([action.student]);
      return newState;

    case DELETE_STUDENT:
      // console.log("action.student", action.student);
      // console.log("state", state);
      newState = state.students.filter(function(student) {
        return student.id !== action.id;
      });
      return newState;

    case GET_CAMPUSES:
      newState.campuses = state.campuses.concat(action.campuses);
      return newState;

    case GET_CAMPUS:
      newState.campuses = state.campuses.concat([action.campus]);
      return newState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

This is how I mount the `Students` and `StudentForm`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Students from "./Students";
import StudentForm from "./StudentForm";
import store from "../store";

import { fetchStudents } from "../reducers";

export default class StudentContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = store.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(fetchStudents());
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => this.setState(store.getState()));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Students students={this.state.students} />
        <StudentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My *store.js*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import createLogger from "redux-logger"; // https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk"; // https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

export default createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, createLogger())
);
```

[image]

Comment: can you show how and where you mount `Students` ?

Comment: @Panther, Yes that would be helpful if i did that. I just updated it.

Comment: Cool. Can you also show your `store.js` ?

Comment: @Panther Sure. Thanks.

Comment: Also can you tell why you have used `var students = this.props.students;` in `Students` render while you also get the state and subscribe to it in that component. Why didn you simply use the state of it instead of relying on props from parent component?

Comment: You need to look into connecting your component to the store. See: http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Comment: Ah—yes. So would that be in that case I should do `var students = this.state.students;` because I am passing the state in `StudentContainer.js` on `<Students students={this.state.students} />`

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the student you are dispatching the action and you are passing the action creator `scrubStudent` to dispatch. You are passing id of the deleted student in that action creator. Now the way you have defined your action creator is like this

```
export function scrubStudent(student) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_STUDENT,
    student
  };
}
```

So the returned value of this function will be an object something like this

```
scrubStudent(5) // returns {type: "DELETE_STUDENT", student: 5}
```

But in your reducer you are comparing the ids like this

```
case DELETE_STUDENT:
      // console.log("action.student", action.student);
      // console.log("state", state);
      newState = state.students.filter(function(student) {
        return student.id !== action.id;
      });
      return newState;
```

In the above code `action.id` is undefined. Instead student id is saved in as `action.student`. So the comparison will return true for all the elements of array. So everytime all the elements will be included in the new state.  So try to change your above code like this

```
case DELETE_STUDENT:
      // console.log("action.student", action.student);
      // console.log("state", state);
      newState = state.students.filter(function(student) {
        return student.id !== action.student;
      });
      return newState;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the view didn't update.  After doing a `console.log('action.id', action.id)` I could see your were right that I was comparing `undefined` there. But after the fact I realized there isn't a `id` property on `action.student` So why are we comparing that?

Comment: You are passing `id` of student, returned from backend when you dispatch the action after your backend result return like `return dispatch(scrubStudent(id));`. So if your backend is returning the id of the student who was deleted then `action.student` will containt that id.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Also i see you are using store.getState() everywhere. I would recommend to use react-redux library [http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html]. When you connect your component with this library your view will automatically get updated whenever your state changes.